# limit / disable VNC display updates

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, headless

I am using the stock "Remote Desktop" VNC server in Ubuntu. Ubuntu is on a 2nd machine, and my primary machine is a 3-monitor Windows 7 setup.

I can VNC into Ubuntu, however I would like to disable screen updates or at least limit the update rate. Too much CPU is being used on Ubuntu when all I really need is VNC for *input*, not for *display* (I connect the Ubuntu machine directly into the 2nd input of my primary monitor; this is a fake KVM in a way).

How can I alter the Ubuntu Remote Desktop settings so that less or no CPU is spent compressing and transmitting display updates? or if this is not possible, what other VNC server software can I install instead? I know this is possible in theory because I already do this in an OS X specific VNC server I found which permits disabling display updates.

(Configured correctly with OS X right now, I can move between left/middle/right displays without any lag, where in fact left=Win7, middle=blank VNC "surface" into OS X, right=Win7. I am trying to do the same with Ubuntu now.)

Comment: What kind of input do you need? If all you're doing is keyboard input you can just connect via ssh and do what you need to do

Comment: keyboard & mouse

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org) might be what you want. It supports Windows, Linux and MacOSX. Only slight lag on heavy network usage. Also copy&paste is supported.

Setup is a bit confusing maybe, but you should be fine with these docs:

- http://synergy-foss.org/tracker/projects/synergy/wiki/Docs
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynergyHowto